# program getting stuck during pthread_join()

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, semaphore

I am currently running this loop to close all my of "factory" threads however the execution doesn't reach the print statement following the `pthread_join()`. My understanding is that if the thread is already terminated then the `pthread_join()` will return instantly. I suspect the factory_thread is hanging

```
 stop_thread_factories = true;

 for(int i=0; i<factories; i++) {
    printf("stopping Candy factory %d\n",i); 
    pthread_join(*factoryThreads[i], NULL);
    printf("Candy factory %d stopped!\n",i);
    //unction waits for the thread specified by thread to terminate. 
}
```

This is the factory thread function and I've added print statements to see where it gets stuck.

```
void* factory_thread(void* arg){

int i = (intptr_t)arg;

int wait_time;
while(stop_thread_factories == false){

    wait_time = rand()%4;   //wait times will be from 0 to 3
    printf("\tFactory %d ships candy & waits %ds\n", i, wait_time);

    //following steps in the outline in the assignment

    candy_t* newCandy = malloc(sizeof(candy_t));
    newCandy->time_stamp_in_ms = current_time_in_ms();
    newCandy->factory_number = i;
    printf("about to insert\n");
    bbuff_blocking_insert(newCandy);
    printf("done inserting\n");
    stats_record_produced(i);
    sleep(wait_time);
}

printf("Candy-factory %d done\n", i);

pthread_exit(NULL);

printf("Just finished the exit call\n");

return NULL;
```

}

However this is the output I am left with and the program hangs on the next line. Any advice or tips would be greatly appreciated! This for a school assignment by the way.

```
stopping Candy factory 0
Candy-factory 0 done
```

Comment: Have you used gdb to figure out where your factory thread is hanging?

Comment: I suspect your suspicion is correct. Do these threads share data? Seeing `bbuff_blocking_insert` and `stats_record_produced` would probably be helpful.

Comment: I think it hangs because the bbuff_blocking_insert() has to wait for a semaphore, however at this point i am finished using the buffer and I want to stop all the threads. If I switch to pthread_cancel from pthread_join() it seems to stop hanging. Would this be a bad practice ?

Comment: When I add debug-printouts I always use:
    fprintf(stderr, "Candy factory %d stopped!\n",i);
instead of:
    printf("Candy factory %d stopped!\n",i);
Things might get buffered. However I cannot see if that is your proble, since the entire code is not here. It is probably not the issue here, but it is a good practce to print to stderr which is normally not buffered.

Comment: I would consider using `pthread_cancel` an extreme choice. As I'm sure you've read, that abruptly ends the thread without cleanup... surely there's a way to gracefully exit.